# Time complexity of the getitem for string object in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I can't find any information about the big O of the `str.__getitem__` method or how it works.

```py
string = str(1001)  # Or any other string
string[-1]
```

It would be great if you could explain (or send url with explanation) how getitem works for string objects.

Comment: Getting anything out of an array/vector/list/tuple or generally a python Sequence (like a string) by *position* within said item is constant time, O(1)